# How to build timeout functionality for this call manually

Tags: jquery

The issue happens rarely , but i need to fix this 
I am doing a file upload through Phonegap .

The issue i am facing is that ,The server has sent back the response , but  it is neither coming into the success or fail and the result is that the progressbar is being shown for ever.

I could't find any timeout functiolity in the framework

My question is that , how can i build out timeout functionality for this request , means stopping the request after 10 seconds

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Transfer Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
        // Do cool things here...
        }

        function getImage() {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
            alert('get picture failed');
        },{
            quality: 50, 
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
            );

        }

        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
            alert(r.response);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getImage();">Upload a Photo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personal opinion: You should try to find out why the response is not coming back as expected, instead of _hacking_ it by using a timeout to pretend it came back.

Answer (score 0):

There is `abort()` method in FileTransfer, which aborts an in-progress transfer.

You can use `setTimeout` with `abort()` method to simulate timeout.

---

But, as @MelanciaUK mentioned in comment, it would be better to find out why the response is not coming back.